# How do I get the interface name created with `ip tuntap add mode tap`

Tags: iproute, tunneling, tap

I want to create a tap with sudo, and then attach the user space program (ssh) to it.

I don't want to hard code the interface name, as multiple users will be using it, so I want the interface name to be generated dynamically.

So I creating the tap like this:

```
sudo ip tuntap add mode tap user $USER
```

How do I get the ip command to return the name of the created interface, so that I can use it to pass to ssh?

Answer (score 0):

The `tuntap` device's Linux programming interface is documented there (with example code): [tuntap.rst](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.rst). The interface name can be asked and then retrieved with the structure passed along the initial `ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, ...)` call. As `ip tuntap` does not display this name, this command alone can't give the information.

Here are two ways to do this.

### Library wrapper

One can add a libc wrapper around [`ioctl()`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/ioctl.2) for this specific goal that can be used at runtime with [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ld.so.8#LD_PRELOAD) thus without having to modify the original tool. Here's a wrapper around the corresponding `ioctl()` use that will print to *stdout* the name of the interface that was just created. Considering OP's `ip tuntap` example uses only 3 times `ioctl()` all related to the *tap* interface, this is fairly safe despite `ioctl()` not always having the same number of parameters for all its uses (here 3 arguments are assumed).

`wraptuntap.c`:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>

#define ioctl ioctl_diverted
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#undef ioctl

#include <stdio.h>

int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long request, void *p) {
        int ret;

        int (*orig_ioctl)(int, unsigned long, void *)=dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"ioctl");
        if ((ret=orig_ioctl(fd, request, p)) != -1 )
                if (request == TUNSETIFF)
                        printf("%s\n",((struct ifreq *)p)->ifr_name);
        return ret;
}
```

remarks:

- `<sys/ioctl.h>` is required for `TUNSETIFF` to be properly defined, but at the same time we can't have `ioctl()` defined or the wrapper's definition would clash. Its initial definition is diverted with [this SO Q/A's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614686/how-to-undef-a-library-function-to-use-our-version-of-same-function/17615531#17615531).
- `ifr_name` is guaranteed to be [null-terminated since kernel 4.13](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=63679112c536289826fec61c917621de95ba2ade) else... well, it's a frail wrapper.

to be compiled for example with:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -o /tmp/wraptuntap.so wraptuntap.c -ldl
```

and be then used like this:

```
# LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/wraptuntap.so ip tuntap add mode tap user 1000
tap0
# LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/wraptuntap.so ip tuntap add mode tap user 1000
tap1
# LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/wraptuntap.so ip tuntap add mode tap user 1000 name foo%d
foo0
# LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/wraptuntap.so ip tuntap add mode tap user 1000 name foo%d
foo1
```

or more useful:

```
# mytun=$(LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/wraptuntap.so ip tuntap add mode tap user 1000 name foo%d)
# ip link show dev "$mytun"
11: foo2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:99:4a:2b:1f:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

As creating such interface isn't very difficult, for production use, creating a dedicated tool, or using an other tool that would display such interface name should be preferred.

### Older [`tunctl`](https://manpages.debian.org/uml-utilities/tunctl.8) (limited to *tap* interfaces):

The older (and thus normally deprecated) `tunctl` tool shipped along UML utilities displays a sentence with the interface name that was used, but will only create mode *tap* (layer 2) interfaces (which is what OP is looking for) and not *tun* (layer 3) interfaces.

Examples:

```
# tunctl -u 1000 -t foo%d
Set 'foo3' persistent and owned by uid 1000
# tunctl -u 1000 -t foo%d | sed -E "s/^Set '([^']+)' .*\$/\1/"
foo4
# ip -d link show dev foo4 # this is a "type tap" interface
13: foo4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c2:05:de:78:16:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 minmtu 68 maxmtu 65521 
    tun type tap pi off vnet_hdr off persist on user 1000 addrgenmode eui64 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535 tso_max_size 65536 tso_max_segs 65535 gro_max_size 65536
```